# In Django, is there a better alternative to using "include" 100+ times in the same document?

Tags: django

I made a Django site that lets users search a database and then display results. Each result is an article and for each article you see the title, author, publication date, etc. This information for each result appears in a box I created with CSS to make the result look nice. Since I may alter the look of the box in the future, I want to use it as a template and then "include" it in my results page. But because there could be over 100 results and each result will display the box, I would need to "include" the box over 100 times with code like the following:

```
{% for article in article_results %}
{% include 'result_box.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is this ok? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See this documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

You can loop through each element passed into your template and generate some HTML depending on it's characteristics.